# BalenaFin v1.0 wifi works on Stretch but not bullseye or buster

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, wireless-adapter

I have a balena fin v1.0 which used to run stretch. It used to perfectly show all available wifi (2.4G and 5G). However I was not able to have the same on the buster image when I got it back in 2020 so I reverted back to stretch. Now, stretch is depreciated with most of the packages and versions absent. I had to upgrade and I decided to install bullseye. Now I am facing the same issue in which wlan0 interface does not get detected. I don’t think it is a hw problem, but more of an interfacing or driver problem that exists in later version of rpi OS. Can someone guide me on how to replicate the wlan0 settings in stretch and manually copy them to the bullseye image?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the 5G WiFi included on newer boards it is mandatory to specify Country Code and later OS require this to be set for all WiFi.

If you follow the recommended setup procedure you should have been prompted to set on first boot but it can be added through the raspi-config menu.

There are a number of questions which explain this in detail.

I have not used a Compute Module but believe it should be similar and you should be able to copy the wpa_supplicant from Stretch and add CC.

Comment: I am already aware of all this, it works perfectly well with stretch. The same does not appear in later versions at all. There is not wifi adapter detected. Even a TP link adaptor attached to the board does not directly show any available wifi options. This is a different issue rather than just something direct and simple and has to do with some drivers that exist in stretch but not in later versions.